# Can methionine peptidase liberate selenomethionine?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

Can methionine peptidase liberate selenomethionine from proteins? I'd be happy to know if *any* can that are active in humans, but am also especially curious about [METAP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAP2).

Comment: `methionine peptidase` is not specific enough. There are many different enzymes (from different organisms) belonging to that "family". Which one are you interested in?

Comment: I'd be happy to know if _any_ can that are active in humans, but am also especially curious about METAP2.

Comment: Are you aware that METAP2 cleaves only N-term Met, and only followed by a subset of the standard amino acids?